# doRedis return errors in windows 8 x64 for different Redis server build

Tags: r, parallel-processing, redis, r-doredis

I am using the Redis server from the link : 
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/rgl/redis/redis-2.4.6-setup-64-bit.exe
with R version3.0.3, doRedis 1.1.0, rredis 1.6.8

The Redis worker end immediately after receiving jobs

```
> redisWorker('jobs')
Waiting for doRedis jobs.
Processing task for job  2  from queue  jobs 
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
ERR unknown command 'EVAL'
```

But with the Redis server from the link : 
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis
and with Redis server build from source on cygwin,

The worker seems to be able to process job, but the master receive error

```
> redisWorker('jobs')
Waiting for doRedis jobs.
Processing task for job  9  from queue  jobs 
Processing task 1 ... from queue jobs jobID 9 
Processing task for job  9  from queue  jobs 
Processing task 2 ... from queue jobs jobID 9 
Processing task for job  9  from queue  jobs 
Processing task 3 ... from queue jobs jobID 9
```

---

```
> registerDoRedis('jobs')
> foreach(i = 1:3)%dopar%i
Error in i : task 1 failed - "object '.doRedisGlobals' not found"
```

Comment: +1 Have you found out the cause of this problem? I have the same problem!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in doRedis. Have you reported this to the package author?

Comment: How did you solve the issue? Have you been able to install doRedis 1.0.5 into R 3.0.1?  I cannot find the way to do that, please follow my question stackoverflow.com/q/22673474/684229

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reported this issue to Bryan Lewis, the author of the doRedis and rredis packages. He replied that he is working to resolve the problem and will update the package on CRAN when it is fixed. In the meantime, you could downgrade to doRedis version 1.0.5 which doesn't have this problem.