# ggpolt2 not supported in new R

Tags: r

I have updated my R to the latest version, that is `R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330)`. My problems is that `ggplot2` does not have a version that supports this `R`.

How can I fix this issue? I mean I guess I need to install an earlier version of `R`, but apart from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673474/how-to-install-doredis-package-version-1-0-5-into-r-3-0-1-on-windows), which refers to Windows I hadn't found any specific way to install an older version.

**UPDATE**

@Yilun Zhang I cannot find the place where I should change the R version. Where should it be:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try again or tomorrow.

You ended up with a (March 28) prerelease of R 3.1.0 which came today (April 10).  The CRAN mirrors were not yet set up for this (at that point: unreleased) version 3.1.0.  They are now.  You should find ggplot2.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, I'll try tomorrow and if it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It worked (+1), but I since I formulated a bit differently my question I'll see if @Yilun Zhang's answer is correct or not.

Comment: Neither can I (on Linux) but that is a different question, isn't it?

Comment: Modified the title so this question will not be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RStudio and have the older r version:

1. go to the navigation bar
2. go to tools
3. Global options
4. there is a section where you can choose the r version

If you are using just the R console, just go to the old r directory and open it.